# Difference between specific time and current time

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

Well i have a time in UNIX format. i need to find the difference between a specific time and current time. if difference is 5 minutes. do something.

```
$sp_time = 1400325952;//Specific time
$currentTime = //current time in UNIX format

$difference = $currentTime - $sp_time;
if($difference >= 5)//if difference is less than or equal to 5minutes
{
    //DO SOME STUFF
}
```

EDIT : How to find the difference in minutes and how to get currenttime?

Comment: Whats your problem here? Describe your problem / error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get minute first using `date()` then compare like

```
$sp_time = 1400325952;//Specific time
$currentTime = time(); // current time 
$difference = $currentTime - $sp_time;
if(date('i',$difference) >= '5') {
    //DO SOME STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for...

```
$sp_time = 1400325952;//Specific time
$currentTime = time(); // current time 
$diff = abs($currentTime - $sp_time);

$mins = round($diff / 60);

if ($mins <= 5) {
echo "difference is less than or equal to 5minutes: $mins";
}
```